# Hey All, want to know whether this Animation is maden on After Effect or not?

Tags: video

Link:-

If this animation can be make on After effects then how to make it

Comment: looks like 3d software like 3d studio max were involved

Comment: @bukkojot thank you for responding the answer Ps I have some basic know how about 3ds Max can you give me the hint where might be 3ds max involve (In skull modelling or animation) thanks in Advance

Comment: 3ds Max can be used in almost every stage, even in final composition

Comment: @bukkojot thanks for your answer and giving me the direction now know where I have to look cheers